# Sql query for inserting all records from one table to another existing table

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql server as my database engine. I need a sql query, so that I can insert all records from one table to another existing table. Both tables are in same DB.

I need to use this query in my code.

Comment: This question is not that simple, we need a lot more details about both tables and what fields exist in each. Do you have an identity field that auto-increments? If so, you'll need to turn that off for the insert in order to keep the same IDs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 insert into destination_table ( field1, field2, field3, ... )
 select field1, field2, field3, ...
 from source_table
```

Comment: @User: this query will work. You need to check to make sure all of the fields line up correctly and that you don't try to insert records that break a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the fields match (are in the same order and of the same type)

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable SELECT * FROM SourceTable
```

Comment: This would create a new TargetTable. OP has indicated the target already exists.

Comment: I already used this code.But this query not works if the destination table is already there

Comment: I thought SELECT INTO created a new target table and will break if the table already exists.

Comment: it will work if we mentioned the fields too

insert into destination_table ( field1, field2, field3, ... )  select field1, field2, field3  from source_table